# iOS: Unable to scroll vertically on UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Since all the questions I found are about disabling vertical scroll, I figured I did something wrong so that my `UIWebView` won't scroll. But I can't figure out why. Here are some chunks of my code:

In my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [window addSubview:viewController.webView];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    NSString *urlString = /* some url string */;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:nil timeoutInterval:10];
    [webView loadRequest:request];      
}
```

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but zooming in and out is disabled as well. If I try to scroll it scrolls the whole window instead of the `UIWebView`. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the UIWebView initialized in Interface Builder or somewhere else?

Comment: @Sam yes, it's initialized in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations that may resolve your problem:

This code:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[window addSubview:viewController.webView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

is a little suspect.  Assuming your `viewController`'s `webView` was initialized and added to your `viewController`'s `view` via Interface Builder there should be no reason to directly add the `webView` as a sub view of the window.  The `webView` is (presumably) a subview of the `viewController`'s `view` and will thus be displayed when you make the `viewController` the `window`'s `rootViewController`.  Similarly, in older versions of iOS before the introduction of the `rootViewController` property, this may have looked like this:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Or in newer iOS versions simply:

```
window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Second, regarding the zooming issue, you may have the `UIWebView` property `scalesPageToFit` set to `NO` (the default.)  If you wish to allow zooming ensure this property is set to `YES`.

I hope this helps,

Sam

Comment: You're right about the zooming issue, but the scrolling issue still persists. `webView` is a subview of `viewController`'s `view` and I changed my code to `window.rootViewController = self.viewController [window makeKeyAndVisible];` but it still wouldn't let me scroll.

Comment: Thats interesting.  Another guess would be that webView.userInteractionEnabled is disabled (but thats unlikely given that the zooming now works.)  Is there any other info about the project you can give?  i.e. any other subviews, custom gesture recognizers, etc.?  Or is this simply a viewController/view with a UIWebView added on top?

Comment: I don't have any other subviews. I added a UIWebView to viewController's view and that's it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say when you try to scroll the web view it scrolls the whole window?  Is your web view placed on top of a UIScrollView?  If it is that is likely the culprit: Apple's docs go out of their way to warn against embedding UITableViews and UIWebViews in UIScrollViews as doing so can mess up touch events.

Comment: No, I don't have a UIScrollView. By "scrolling the whole window" I meant that if my UIWebView page was longer, I just can't scroll down. When I try to, the whole view (window) is pulled up and shows that grey background area as if there's nothing below. I don't know the exact terms, hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay two last things: I notice you're setting the cachePolicy to nil which is giving me a compiler warning.  Although it may not make a difference, perhaps try changing it to one of the constants listed in NSURLRequest's docs (I don't know much about these or their implications.) Second, what web page are you trying to load?